# How to get data from DB table between two specific dates(specified by user) by SQL statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ucanaccess

Here is my code..I got error

> "UCanAccess error - net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: incompatible data type in operation: at following line..

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)

public void showCeilingMaterials(Site_Details site_detail) 
{
    String sql="SELECT SiteName, SUM(PlanTileQuantity), SUM(PlanTilePrice), SUM(PellingQuantity),SUM(PellingPrice), SUM(PowderQuantity),SUM(PowderPrice),SUM(LpattiQuantity),SUM(LpattiPrice),LpattiSize,SUM(CeilingTotalPrice) FROM CeilingMaterials Where SiteName='?' AND Date<='?' AND Date>=?";
        try (PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            java.util.Date parsed = format.parse(site_detail.getStartDate());
            java.sql.Date sql_date1 = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
            format.format(sql_date1);
            java.util.Date parsed1 = format.parse(site_detail.getEndDate());
            java.sql.Date sql_date2 = new java.sql.Date(parsed1.getTime());
            format.format(sql_date2);
            pStmt.setString(1, site_detail.getSiteName());
            pStmt.setDate(2, sql_date1);
            pStmt.setDate(2,sql_date2);
            ResultSet rs= pStmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                showCeil.setSiteName(rs.getString("SiteName"));
                showCeil.setTileQuantity(rs.getString("PlanTileQuantity"));
                showCeil.setTilePrice(rs.getString("PlanTilePrice"));
                showCeil.setPellingQuantity(rs.getString("PellingQuantity"));
                showCeil.setPellingPrice(rs.getString("PellingPrice"));
                showCeil.setLpattiQuantity(rs.getString("LpattiQuantity"));
                showCeil.setLpattiPrice(rs.getString("LpattiPrice"));
                showCeil.setLpattiSize(rs.getString("LpattiSize"));
                showCeil.setPowderQuantity(rs.getString("PowderQuantity"));
                showCeil.setPowderPrice(rs.getString("PowderPrice"));
                showCeil.setTotalCeilingPrice(rs.getString("CeilingTotalPrice"));
                show_ceil_w=new Site_Details_Show_Interface();
                show_ceil_w.showGui(showCeil);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the single qoutes from the parameter `FROM CeilingMaterials Where SiteName=? AND Date<=? AND Date>=?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL command text for a parameterized query must never include quotes (or other delimiters) around parameter placeholders. You have the following, which is incorrect:

```sql
... Where SiteName='?' AND Date<='?' AND Date>=?
```

Specifically, it is `Date<='?'` that is causing the error cited in the question, although the error message is slightly different in newer versions of UCanAccess (in this case, v3.0.2):

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.2 incompatible data types in combination

Instead, you need to have

```sql
... Where SiteName=? AND [Date]<=? AND [Date]>=?
```

*[Note that `Date` is a reserved word (built-in function name) in Access so you should use square brackets around it if you want to refer to a column named `Date`.]*

Once that error is corrected then other errors in your SQL manifest themselves. The next one you will have to address is:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.2 expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: PUBLIC.CEILINGMATERIALS.SITENAME

because you have included `SiteName` in your list of columns to be returned, but it is not part of an aggregate function (e.g., `MIN()`, `MAX()`) or a GROUP BY clause. You have that same problem with `LpattiSize` as well.

You also have

```java
pStmt.setDate(2, sql_date1);
pStmt.setDate(2,sql_date2);
```

where you have assigned a value to parameter #2 twice (so parameter #3 has no value).

Finally, be aware that when you SUM() a column without providing an alias, as in

```sql
SELECT ... SUM(PlanTileQuantity), ...
```

the resulting column will *not* be named "PlanTileQuantity". UCanAccess will assign it an arbirtary column name like "C1", "C2", etc.. It is always best to explicitly assign an alias, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT ... SUM(PlanTileQuantity) AS SumOfPlanTileQuantity, ...
```

Comment: Gord Thompson, But stii I got the same error as above after correcting sql statement..